# Touchpad working, but keyboard and mouse not working

Tags: 16.04, touchpad, hardware

### My problem cannot be solved anymore because I reinstalled ubuntu 16.04. It works well.

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 in my old laptop Acer Aspire 3830 and installed the touchpad with the method I was not able to remember. After that day, I didn't use it. Today, I turned on my laptop. The keyboard and mouse were not working, but only the touchpad and some functional keys like on/off touchpad worked.

It is not a hardware problem, because I can use the keyboard in the other OS after multi-booting it.

I can edit grub at the boot menu, but cannot edit in Ubuntu desktop after entering the password using a screen keyboard.

Let me know possible solutions. Thanks.

Comment: See if the solutions here can help you:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/299567/touchpad-not-working-on-acer-laptop

Comment: My laptop worked well except for recognition of touchpad. It seems that fixing the touchpad problem caused the new problem. Your link seems to be different from my situation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I misinterpreted the question.
Please check this:

[USB devices not work after installation of ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/482154/usb-devices-not-work-after-installation-of-ubuntu-14-04)

The problem might be the usb configurations.

Comment: My problem cannot be solved anymore because I reinstalled ubuntu 16.04. Thanks for your comments.